# How can I install the mat2vec Python package?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the `mat2vec` Python package (more info here: https://github.com/materialsintelligence/mat2vec) typing the usual `pip install mat2vec`. But the output is

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mat2vec (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mat2vec
```

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do the following:

1- Download package root directory: https://github.com/materialsintelligence/mat2vec.

2- Open a python terminal and navigate to the downloaded package root directory path.

3- Run the command: `pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt`.

4- Run the command: `python setup.py instal`.

5- Run the command: `cde data download`.

Answer (score 0):

Your system may have 2 different versions of Python and your pip command may call the Python 2.x version.

To solve this problem, you should install Python 3 version of pip with these steps:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

After this process, please check is it successfully installed or not with this command:

```
pip3 --version
```

It must give you a result like this:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

After all these steps you can install your desired Python package with:

```
pip3 install mat2vec
```

If it requires a sudo permission please use:

```
sudo pip3 install mat2vec
```

I hope this is your solution, if it is not please share the result with me. I may help you, thanks.

I did check the GitHub page of your targeted package and the solution must be the @TheRockSays 's solution.

Comment: In reality I have Python 3.7 (on Windows 10, with anaconda)

Comment: @Gio I checked the github page of mat2vec, I could not able to find their pip package install option, they may not have their package in pip. Please follow their or TheRockSays 's installation directions.